# Getting data from different SQL tables and adding it to comboBox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, listbox

I have the following query that gets two different columns from two different tables and add the columns to a `comboBox` or `ListBox` in C#.
This is my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("(select client_name from clients) UNION (select publication_name from publications)" + suffix, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
```

I checked and got 5 rows in the `dataset.Tables[0]`, 2 from the table *publishers* and 3 from the table *clients*.

Now after this, I wrote this code to add this fetched data to a `comboBox`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (ds.Tables[0].TableName.ToString() == "clients" + suffix)
     comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["clients" + suffix].ToString());
   if (ds.Tables[0].TableName.ToString() == "publications" + suffix)
     comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["publications" + suffix].ToString());
}
```

Not working! Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working!

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }
```